# Javascript regex for semicolon not in complex nested quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way that a regex would match all of these instances where the semicolons would not match when in quotes but would match when not in quotes-

```
";" (match this instance); ";"
';' (match this instance); ';'
"";";" (match this instance); "";";"
';";"' (match this instance); ';";"'
```

This is just an example and the semicolons can be preceded by numbers letters etc. To provide a bit more context, take for example this case -

```
'This is a \n ; test "statement;" ;' (match this instance); "This is also a test;'Statement;'"
```

The `(match this instance);` means that that instance of the semicolon should be matched. Also higher levels of `"` and `'` nesting is possible, so looking for a global solution.

Also it should match if the quotes are escaped with a backslash as so -

```
\"(match this instance);\"
"\";\""(match this instance);\"(match this instance);\"
```

Comment: just /[;]/g ???

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do here. If you are just trying to find every semi-colon, this is pretty simple

Comment: I'm trying to find every instance of the semicolon not in quotes or nested quotes.

Comment: Regular expressions are not good for that task. They can't easily tell "inside" from "outside".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the character series that do *not* constitute a "valid" semi-colon, and then match the semi-colon, ...etc. This way the whole text will be matched, but the semi-colons will be in separate matches:

```js
let regex = /(?:\\.|(["'])(?:\\.|.)*?\1|[^;])+|;/gms;

let test = String.raw`";" (match this instance); ";"
';' (match this instance); ';'
"";";" (match this instance); "";";"
';";"' (match this instance); ';";"'
\"(match this instance);\"
"\";\""(match this instance);\"(match this instance);\"`

let matches = test.match(regex);

console.log(matches);
```

Whenever a match is just one character (it will be a semi-colon) it is to be considered the actual match you'd be looking for.